# FB.init and FB.ui doesn't work in IE7 in Canvas application

Tags: internet-explorer-7, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Site I'm talking about is here:

https://www.facebook.com/kleenexau/app_295074103899059

If you run it in popular browsers - it works. If you run it in IE7 then it magically stops working. I was digging around more then 1 day so far, and decided to post this question here.

The code I'm using to connect to fb is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({
    appId: _FBAPPID, xfbml: true, status: true, cookie: true, oauth: true,
    channelUrl: "//sharethesoftness.kleenex.com.au/channel.php"
});
</script>
```

When you click the button this code is triggered:

```
function jumpToChoose(data) {
    if(data) {
        window.location = _SITE + "choose.html";
    }
}

function startButtonClickHandler() {

    $("#startButton").fadeOut();
    $("#ajaxloader").fadeIn();

    FB.ui({
        method : "permissions.request",
        "perms" : 'user_hometown,friends_hometown,email' /*publish_stream,user_about_me,friends_about_me,*/
    }, jumpToChoose);
}
```

Adding 'http' to channelUrl doesn't work either. I have no clue what is causing this problem. I tried many solutions, also this: http://blog.coderubik.com/2011/03/cookies-and-facebook-canvas-apps/.

Any help would be appreciated. If you need any other details, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this at the very top of your page and see if it work.

```
<?php
    header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
?>
```

It seems that IE is preventing you from storing third-party cookies, this header will enable your cookie to survive any privacy setting.